# *why* should we not use optical drives on SCU server ports?

Tags: storage, sata, optical-media

So I'm building out a VM/file server using a [Supermicro X9SRA](http://supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon/C600/X9SRA.cfm), and as I'm figuring out where I want to plug everything in I end up learning [about the SCU](https://citrixready.citrix.com/intel-corporation/intel-c602-chipset-4-port-sata-storage-control-unit.html) on the Intel chipsets.   I find a few things [here](https://hardforum.com/threads/what-is-sata-scu.1712949/) [here](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkStation-Workstations/When-to-use-SCU-SATA/td-p/925205) [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/838578/s-sata-vs-i-sata-pch-scu) that basically say "Don't plug optical drives into the SCU ports!" ... but ***none of them seem to say why***.

So being the skeptical bastard that I am (plus the fact that I have a not-yet-commissioned server sitting on a bench to play with) I immediately plug an optical drive into one of the SCU ports, boot up a liveCD linux image, and it works just fine.  Maybe it's slower, maybe there are some things it won't do, but for five minutes of random messing around I can't seem to determine how this connection is in any way different than if I'd plugged it into a "regular" SATA port.

Anyone have technical details on why this might be?  Or is this just some old wives tale?   ;-)

Comment: have you read this (sorry, you have :)? https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkStation-Workstations/When-to-use-SCU-SATA/td-p/925205 seems like issue is that SCU port is 4x SATA (up to 24Gbps ??) which is not very useful for optical drives but can be used with SAS expanders/splitters

Comment: @aaaaaa -- Yes, but the only thing relevant is says is "since ODDs aren't supported on SCU" -- but my testing shows they work just fine.  So is this statement simply not true?   Or are there other things I should consider somewhere?